# How can I display team's dealt damage in competitive mode?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In the past I was able to display a bar where every team member's delt damage was shown. I could do this by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> (scoreboard) and then <kbd>Z</kbd>.
This was the default setting, but meanwhile this setting seems to be removed.
I can neither find a setting to change that key nor I can display that bar with any other key.

Does someone know if that might have been removed or am I just too stupid to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile CS:GO natively displays the ADR in the scoreboard if you click on the chart icon in the top right corner of the scoreboard.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean ADR? If not, I don't think there was ever a setting to see every team member's damage dealt in matchmaking.

Comment: There was. It was no live bar, but a sumup of the former rounds.